# System Verilog Testbench waveforms no data

Tags: simulation, system-verilog, quartus, register-transfer-level

I'm trying to develop a code which acts like a logical calculator; I've managed to compile both the code and the testbench without any errors. Here is the code:

```
   module AriLogCal(
                    input logic [3:0] OpA, OpB, //Operands A and B. The two numbers we will operate on.
                    input logic [2:0] DoOpt,        //Operator. Determines the operation we will do.
                    input logic EqualTo, AC,        //Interrupts. AC resets, EqualTo transfers data to display.
                    output logic [6:0] S2, S1, S0   //Seven-Segement LEDS. Shows each digit separately.
                 );

logic [7:0] result;                                     //Result. 
Mathematical operation result data is stored here.
logic [3:0] D2, D1, D0;                                 //Digits. Determines 
the number/symbol/deactivation for each respective SevenSeg.

always begin
if(AC)begin //Makes all the numbers display 0 if AC returns TRUE
result=8'b00000000;
S0=7'b1111110;
S1=7'b1111110;
S2=7'b1111110;        
end
else if(EqualTo)begin //Does this stuff if EqualTo returns TRUE

//Part 1: Operation. Decides the relationship between Operand A and B and stores data under "result"
case(DoOpt) 
3'b000:result=OpA+OpB; //Addition
3'b001:begin              //Subtraction
    if(OpB>OpA)
        result=OpB-OpA;
    else
        result=OpA-OpB;
end 
3'b010:result=OpA*OpB; //Multiplication
3'b011:begin                //Division
    if(OpB)
        result=OpA/OpB;
    else
        result=0;
end
3'b100:begin
    if(OpA&&OpB)              //Logical AND
        result=8'b00000001;
    else
        result=8'b00000000;
end
3'b101:begin
    if(OpA||OpB)              //Logical OR
        result=8'b00000001;
    else result=8'b00000000;
end
endcase

//Part 2: Digits. Dissects the value of "result" into its decimal digits and stores them in logic "D"
if(!OpB&&DoOpt==3'b011)      //This will show "Err" on LED displays
D0=4'b1010;
else if(result<10)begin //Single Digit. S1 and S2 is temporarily set to zero
D0=result;
D1=4'b0000;
D2=4'b0000;
end
else if(result<100)begin //Double digit. S2 is temporarily set to zero
D0=result%10;
D1=result/10;
D2=4'b0000;
end
else begin                   //Triple digit. 
D2=result/100;
result=result%100;
D1=result/10;
D0=result%10;
end


//Part 3: Blanks. Adds blanks and negative sign depending on operation type, according to requirements
case(DoOpt)
3'b000:D2=4'b1011;       //Addition deactivates S2
3'b001:begin             
if(OpB>OpA)                 //Subtraction deactivates or shows negative sign 
for S2
    D2=4'b1100;
else
    D2=4'b1011;
end
3'b011:begin                 //Multiplcation is skipped. 
if(!OpB)begin               //Division has two options:
    D0=4'b1010;             //If divider is 0, this will show "Err" on LED 
displays
    D1=4'b1010;
    D2=4'b1010;
end else                        //Otherwise, S2 is deactivated
D2=4'b0000;
end
3'b100:begin                //Logical AND deactivates S2 and S1
    D2=4'b1011;
    D1=4'b1011;
end
3'b101:begin                //Logical OR deactivates S2 and S1
    D2=4'b1011;
    D1=4'b1011;
end
endcase

//Part 4: Display. Prints the digits from "D" onto its respective Seven Segment LED S
case(D0)
 4'b1010: S0<=7'b0000101; //D0=10 means S0 displays R
 4'b1001: S0<=7'b1110011; //9
 4'b1000: S0<=7'b1111111; //8
 4'b0111: S0<=7'b1110000; //7
 4'b0110: S0<=7'b1011111; //6
 4'b0101: S0<=7'b1011011; //5
 4'b0100: S0<=7'b0110011; //4
 4'b0011: S0<=7'b1111001; //3
 4'b0010: S0<=7'b1101101; //2
 4'b0001: S0<=7'b0110000; //1
 4'b0000: S0<=7'b1111110; //0
 endcase
 case(D1)
 4'b1011: S1<=7'b0000000; //D1=11 means S1 deactivates
 4'b1010: S1<=7'b0000101; //D1=10 means S1 displays R
 4'b1001: S1<=7'b1110011; //9
 4'b1000: S1<=7'b1111111; //8
 4'b0111: S1<=7'b1110000; //7
 4'b0110: S1<=7'b1011111; //6
 4'b0101: S1<=7'b1011011; //5
 4'b0100: S1<=7'b0110011; //4
 4'b0011: S1<=7'b1111001; //3
 4'b0010: S1<=7'b1101101; //2
 4'b0001: S1<=7'b0110000; //1
 4'b0000: S1<=7'b1111110; //0
 endcase
 case(D2)
 4'b1100: S2<=7'b0000001; //D2=12 means S2 shows negative sign
 4'b1011: S2<=7'b0000000; //D2=11 means S2 deactivates
 4'b1010: S2<=7'b1001111; //D2=10 means S2 displays E
 4'b1001: S2<=7'b1110011; //9
 4'b1000: S2<=7'b1111111; //8
 4'b0111: S2<=7'b1110000; //7
 4'b0110: S2<=7'b1011111; //6
 4'b0101: S2<=7'b1011011; //5
 4'b0100: S2<=7'b0110011; //4
 4'b0011: S2<=7'b1111001; //3
 4'b0010: S2<=7'b1101101; //2
 4'b0001: S2<=7'b0110000; //1
 4'b0000: S2<=7'b1111110; //0
 endcase
 end
 end
 endmodule
```

and here is the current testbench (this is a shorter version; I'm still trying to find the problem behind this)

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module AriLogCal_tb;
logic [3:0] in_OpA;
logic [3:0] in_OpB;
logic [2:0] in_DoOpt;
logic in_EqualTo;
logic in_AC;
logic [6:0] out_S2, out_S1, out_S0;

AriLogCal AriLogCal_inst0(.OpA(in_OpA), .OpB(in_OpB), .DoOpt(in_DoOpt), 
.EqualTo(in_EqualTo), .AC(in_AC), .S2(out_S2), .S1(out_S1), .S0(out_S0));

initial begin
in_EqualTo=1'b0;
in_AC=1'b0;


in_OpA = 4'b0111; in_OpB = 4'b0010; in_DoOpt = 3'b000; 
in_EqualTo = 1'b0;#100;

$finish;

end
endmodule
```

Both of these files are able to individually compile successfully, with no errors. However, when I try to compile them in the RTL Simulator, I get these results:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4LCb9TUml0WWVsZEYtcG03LVk/view?usp=sharing

Why do I still get "No Data" in my results, despite successful compilation? Immediate help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your model did not do anything besides time '0',  then it waited for some reson for #100 and finished. Where is your clock? state machine? activities? And as the compiler suggested, where is the control of the 'always' block? did it ever finish the simulation on its own? it should have hanged there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any event/time blockers in `AriLogCal`'s always block.`always begin` is an infinite loop. It will continuously re-evaluate and prevent the simulator from moving to the next time step.

It should be changed `always_comb begin`, which has an inherited time blocking and will only trigger the at time 0 and when an stimulus signal changes. Alternative you could use the Verilog auto-sensitivity `@*` (or the synonymous `@(*)`) and change the statement to `always @* begin`. `always_comb` is superior to `always @*` because it with through compiling errors if basic synthesis requirements are not stratified (ex: register is assigned in only one always block and no blocking `@` or `#` statements in the  always block).

FYI: You should not be using non-blocking (`<=`) assignments in combinational logic; blocking (`=`) assignments are preferred. Non-blocking assignments should be used in `always_ff` and the occasional `always_latch`.